# Git merge says already up-to-date with master but my branch doesn’t contain the latest changes

Tags: git, version-control, git-merge

I’m working on a branch “ABC” cloned from master and since someone’s changes just got merged to master branch my code needs their latests changes. I used git merge and sent everything in a new commit, However, when I use hit pull, git merge, and fetch it says “already up-to-date”, not sure if I did something wrong but my code isn’t synced with what’s on master.

Git status says “Your branch is up to date with origin/feature/ABC”

Ps: I can’t modify master without approval, so preferably I’d like to not mess with master if possible

Comment: How about `git merge master` or `git rebase master`.

Comment: Git merge master says “already up-to-date” and can I use rebase if I don’t want to modify master in remote?

Comment: My understanding is `merge` and `rebase` effectively do the same thing -- the difference is in the history.

Comment: The thing you probably didn't notice is that your local `master` branch doesn't contain the latest changes either. [@torek's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/73941010/184546) will get you where you need to be.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`git pull` means:

1. run `git fetch`, then
2. run a second Git command, `git merge` by default, but you can set things up to be different if you like.

If you run it with *no arguments* (as you presumably did), this means:

- `git fetch origin` (usually and in your case), and then
- `git merge HEAD@{upstream}` (assuming your chosen second command is `git merge`).

The upstream is a setting, per-branch: you can change it if you want, but that's not what you want here.  Your `git status` output shows that the upstream of your `feature/ABC` is your `origin/feature/ABC`, which is correct.

But what this all means is:

- the `git fetch` step obtains all the new commits, including those on *their* `master` branch, so that your `origin/master` is updated, and then
- the `git merge` step merges with the *old* commits you already had all along on your `origin/feature/ABC` that corresponds to your `feature/ABC`.

Hence, `git pull` is not what you want!

What you want, presumably, is:

1. run `git fetch` or `git fetch origin`; then
2. run `git merge origin/master`.

As you're a Git newbie, I recommend *avoiding* `git pull`.  Run separate `git fetch` and second-command steps, so that you know exactly which step *failed* if one step does fail.  This is important later when it comes to recovering from this failure.

If you prefer to run `git pull`, though, the combined convenience form is—partly for historical reasons—`git pull origin master`, rather than `git pull origin origin/master`, even though you want the merge step to use `origin/master`.

Comment: This answer is probably 100% accurate, but it is way to complex for the simple question being asked! It's clearly a newb question, and so an answer that covers all the nuances only a pro will want to know is too confusing! ;)